# ORA 904 - Error compiling function that references function from another schema - has execute privilege

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting a "ORA-00904 invalid identifier" error trying to use a function from another schema inside a function in my schema. I am using the fully qualified name of the function, and have execute privilege on the function through a granted role.

Executing the function directly from my schema works. But calling that function from a function in my schema doesn't, and gives the 904 error.

### Example:

I am trying to compile a procedure called proc_A in a schema called schema_A.

proc_A uses the output of a function called proc_B from schema_B.

schema_A has access to proc_B through a role. schema_A is able to run proc_B directly, but is cannot use it in a function/procedure. Using it in a procedure causes a compilation failure.

Below is a code sample that demonstrates the problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_b.proc_b
RETURN  DATE IS
BEGIN
    RETURN sysdate;
END;
/


CREATE ROLE run_query
/


GRANT EXECUTE ON schema_b.proc_b TO run_query
/
GRANT run_query TO schema_a
/



-- this will fail to compile with the ORA-904 invalid identifier error
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_a.proc_a
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT schema_b.proc_b() FROM dual) LOOP --> this function call causes the error
        NULL;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 5;
END;
/
```

---

Running Oracle 11g R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The privilege must be direct (not granted to a `ROLE`).

If you change the grant from:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON schema_b.proc_b TO run_query
/
```

To:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON schema_b.proc_b TO schema_a;
/
```

The dependent procedure in `schema_a` should compile.

Comment: That does work. I thought the whole point of the roles was so that you don't need to individually grant privileges?

Comment: Thanks @ngundling Yeah it can take some getting used-to.  But it is by design--roles work in some situations but are not equivalent to direct grants, and object dependencies like this require the latter.  I think Tom Kyte describes the reasoning for the requirement well here:  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319

Comment: Roles are for managing groups of end users and can be enabled and disabled on the fly. The PL/SQL compiler needs something more concrete.